# How to match a pattern of words in a string using regular expressions in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a specific pattern of words in a string using regular expressions in Python. The pattern I'm looking for is \n\d)\s followed by one or more words, up to the next newline character. Here's an example string:

```
xxxxxxxxx.... \n1) Hello world \n2) This is a test \n3) I'm trying to match this pattern \nxxxxxx.....
```

I want to extract the following matches from the string:

```
1) Hello world
2) This is a test
3) I'm trying to match this pattern
```

I've tried using the regular expression pattern `\n\d\)\s\w+(?:\s\w+)*?(?=\n)`, but it's not giving me the matches I expect. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: you can process it without using regex if the target sentences are in between `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Using `\s` can also match a newline, and `\w` does not match `'`

One option could be to match at least a single word character followed by the rest of the line:

```
^\d\)[^\S\n]+\w.*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d\)` Match a single digit (or use `\d+` for 1 or more) followed by `)`
- `[^\S\n]+` Match 1+ whitespace chars without newlines
- `\w` Match a single word character
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/STHA9D/1).

If there must be newlines to the left and the right, and you want to broaden the match with at least a single non whitespace character using `\S` you can use lookarounds:

```
(?<=\n)\d+\)[^\S\n]+\S.*(?=\n)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lp28md/1).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would solve this:

```
\n(\d+\)[^\n]+)
```

Explanation:

1. search for a new line: `\n`
2. start a capturing group: `(`
3. find numbers (one ore more): `\d`
4. find close bracket after number `\)`
5. match any not new lines: `[^\n"]+`
6. close capturing group: `)`

Then you can access the match you are looking for from the capturing group: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you may try:

```py
import re

string = "xxxxxxxxx.... \n1) Hello world \n2) This is a test \n3) I'm trying to match this pattern \nxxxxxx....."

pattern = r'\n\d+\)\s(.+)'
matches = re.findall(pattern, string)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

output:

```
Hello world 
This is a test 
I'm trying to match this pattern
```